# Cocos2d-x load a very large image

Tags: large-files, cocos2d-x, render-to-texture

I have to load a very large image(which format is png) to my game as the background, and the game is developed in cocos2d-x. 
The question is if i keep the image in the memory it will take too much memory space , and if i split it into many pieces and load it dynamically, the frame rates will drop to very low when it renders the image data to textures. So is there a way i can get 'less memory' and 'fluent' at the same time? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

will Texture Packer becomes a good choice?